# Windows 10 apps and games use all hard disk

Tags: windows-10, storage

My friend have strange problem. He told me that he can't open any image (he's not computer guy), and on first look, i saw that available disk space is 0. Looking at `Settings -> Storage -> This PC (C:)` show that Apps & Games uses 414 GB from 500 GB HDD. I'm not using Windows, so I cant help him so much. After clicking on section Apps & Games, all apps and games are listed, but biggest is around 2 GB, and others are small. The all can occupy maybe 20-30 GB. 
Looking at User directory,it's using about 20 GB. I inspected nearly all folders and can't find what is using his space on HDD.

Windows 10 build is 14393.576 on Toshiba Satellite c875 Laptop.

[image: Storage usage][image: Apps by size]

Comment: Have your friend run WinDirStat as an **Administrator** and submit a screenshot to imgur of the resulting output.  Your question cannot be answered without this information.  The information displayed in the screenshots are only for the current user, it's clear by the usage, multiple users are on the pc.  Update your question, do not submit a comment, with this required and requested screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It is probably *data* from the games, or downloaded web pages, that clutters his machine.

Try using Windows Disk Cleanup to make more room:

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key to get a *Search* prompt and type *Cleanup*.
- Click on *Disk Cleanup* and select Drive C if there is more than one choice.
- Click on *Clean up system files* for a more thorough job.
- Check all the options (e.g. *Downloaded Program Files*, *Temporary Internet Files*, etc.).
- Click *OK*.
- Confirm that you want to permanently delete the files... and wait.

Depending on previous Windows installations, *Cleanup* may take a few minutes or a few *hours.*

Hopefully, this will create some empty space. For efficient use, a Windows PC needs *at least* a few GB free for swap space, temporary files and the like. If there is less than 20 GB or so free after this cleanup, have the user delete any saved games, and if that is not sufficient, *uninstall* any infrequently used application from the Windows *Programs and Features* control panel applet.

Now, if you have enough room, install a tool such as [TreeSize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) to analyze file usage on the entire disk. It should show you the the actual files and folders taking up so much room. The issue will then be deciding which can be safely deleted -- your friend will need to research each game to see what can go.

[image: TreeSize Free]

Comment: Tried all from above already. Disk cleanup released 20 MB of space, there is no data from apps. Most apps is uninstaled in a meantime which fried about 3 GB. Still,in setting shows that apps and games uses 400 GB. Went through all root folders and inspect size, and combined is about 70GB.

Comment: See edit above on GUI for folder size.